# Will calories from drinking spirits effect my diet

Tags: diet, alcohol

How do alcohol calories work.  I'm not talking beer, but straight gin or vodka.  I've heard it's about 100 calories per ounce, and it's not digested by your normal digestion system, but your liver.  What kind of effect do alcohol calories have on the body.  And can I get away with having a gin every night on a strict diet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, with alcohol, the extra calories are really not the main thing to worry about. There are a lot of other changes going on in the body.
Here's a [good place to start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcoholic_beverage#Effects_of_alcohol_on_health).

Are you ok having a drink every now and then? Sure, I don't see a problem with that. But a spirit every night might not be what you need on a diet (or even off a diet).

Especially on a "strict" diet, your body is already being pushed hard by the caloric deficit; I would do my best to help it out, not strain it even more.

Answer (score 7):

Alcohol contains 7 calories per gram, ~70 per fluid ounce, and ~100 per jigger<sup>[1](http://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/generic/gin)</sup>. It is converted in the liver to acetate which is given priority in metabolism in the same way that carbs & protein are given priority over fat<sup>[2](http://www.leangains.com/2010/07/truth-about-alcohol-fat-loss-and-muscle.html)</sup>. As long as you properly count the calories in the alcohol you drink, you should be able to work it in to your diet.